# Q: How i can append attach on <div> iframe with src adress?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How i can append attach on  iframe with src adress?

How i can manipulate div attaching on it iframe object with content?!
(Included into Wordpress page) by using brackets for testing....

I want to make custom js included into wordpress page without use jquery 
(if u have any ideas cause i read the wordpress does support jquery libraries) could be good. I accept and jquery too as idea. I choose to do not use jquery cause i think wordpress does not support it.

javascript

```
<script async="" type="text/javascript">
    var Divfrm = document.getElementById('#frame');
    var ifrm = document.createElement('iframe');

    function evtTrigger(){
        document.addEventListener('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        Divfrm = document.appendChild(ifrm);
        ifrm.setAttribute('src','http://google.com');
    });

    function close(){
        ifrm = document.Detach(Divfrm);
    };

    return DivFrm = document.InnerHTML = ('');
</script>
```

html

```
     <!--I'din't know why worpress cover field "script" tag?!-->

            <h1 style="color: aqua; text-align: left;">Magic fountain mod example script</h1>

            <p style="color: aqua; text-align: left; margin-left: 20px;">Can you ever saw glow fountain?, that was is available now</p>

            <div id="frame" style="outline-color: mediumturquoise; background: rgba(0,128,128,0.2); overflow-y: scroll; height: 400px; margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 30px; color: mediumaquamarine;">



     <!--here div was as role dialog ^^^>

            <p>Explanation about code here text</p>

            </div>

            <div>
                <button onclick="evtTrigger()">Show video</button>
                <button onclick="close()">Hide this</button>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Question is really unclear. I assume you want to add the `ifrm` inside `Divfrm` on clicking somewhere which fires the `evtTrigger` function. And then remove the `ifrm` when calling `close()`

If this is your goal, try this

```
var Divfrm = document.getElementById('#frame');
var ifrm = document.createElement('iframe');

function evtTrigger(){ 
    Divfrm.appendChild(ifrm);
    ifrm.setAttribute('src', 'http://google.com');
};

function close(){ 
    Divfrm.removeChild(ifrm); 
};
```

By the way, you can't load google.com inside your iframe because browser won't allow it. If this is just as an example, then it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

When the user clicks Show Video, it will call `evtTrigger()` -- but all that function does is attach the click listener to the document, it doesn't run that handler function. In fact, after clicking Show Video, after that every click on the page will run your handler function.

You're also appending the iframe to the entire document, not just your div (hence you're using `document.appendChild` instead of `Divfrm.appendChild`) -- that's probably not what you want.

So remove your addEventListener code, put the iframe appending code directly in the evtTrigger function, and change `Divfrm = document.appendChild(ifrm)` to just `Divfrm.appendChild(ifrm)`. Then it should work.